# Wrap EAP in Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I was trying to wrap a EAP in a Task with following code.

```
public static async Task<string> Caller()
    {
        var ret = await RunProgram();

        return ret;
    }

    public static async Task<string> RunProgram()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> source = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
        {
            source.SetResult("hello");
        };
        process.Start();

        return await source.Task;
    }
```

However,the Exited Event never gets fired. Could someone guide me on what am doing wrong here ?

Please note that above code is a prototype, the 'event-not-firing' scenario happens in the real scenario as well.

Comment: There must be 10 C# questions a day that want to use `async void`... Stop! step away from the keyboard and stop hacking code, please go and read the documentation on `async`, `await` and `Task`.... though i must admit this is not your problem...

Comment: @TheGeneral, the void was typed in as I was building the prototype for posting here. It wasn't part of original code. Sorry, I have changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without addressing any other issue.

[Process.EnableRaisingEvents Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets whether the Exited event should be raised when the
>   process terminates.

**Remarks**

> The EnableRaisingEvents property indicates whether the component
>   should be notified when the operating system has shut down a process.
>   The EnableRaisingEvents property is used in asynchronous processing to
>   notify your application that a process has exited. To force your
>   application to synchronously wait for an exit event (which interrupts
>   processing of the application until the exit event has occurred), use
>   the WaitForExit method

**Example**

```
var p = Process.Start(startInfo);
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExited);
```

Comment: Thanks General, though the solution you mentioned was restricted to the example code, it prompted me to look at different part of code, which lead me to solution. I was earlier under impression issue was with the TaskCompletionSource part, but issue, as in the example was in a different part

Comment: @AnuViswan no problems, im glad you sorted it

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable event raising property of the Process

like this

```
var process = new Process

{
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(processPath)
    {
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};
```